# RecyclerView & View Pager .No adapter attached?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I am using a viewPager with few fragments having RecyclerView.But problem is I got error "No adapter attached".Is there any problem with viewPager with recyclerView??

Comment: Is it the `ViewPager` or the `RecyclerView` that doesn't have an adapter? Code would be helpful.

Comment: Post the corresponding part of code

Answer (score 0):

Code would be helpful,
but the issue is most probably with the RecyclerView and the error should be smth like "No adapter attached; skipping layout"
For RecyclerView it is important to set an Adapter and LayoutManager, otherwise it wont show anything